# Meaning of "<-" in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2

I am reviewing a code from other developers and I saw some unfamiliar codes. One of the unfamiliar code is this.

```
identifier <- map["id"]
```

identifier is a variable inside the struct. Can you please help me what is the use of "<-" symbol? I tried googling it but I can't find the right answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @EricD I will ask the other developer about the lib he use. Thank you. :)

Comment: Probably from https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<-` operator is not part of Swift.

There's nothing in the [Swift manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID418) about it.

It is a custom operator defined by a third-party library you're using in your project.

If you do a `CMD-click` on it, Xcode should open the operator's declaration

Answer (score 0):

The Developer used ObjectMapper.
https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

That's why. Thank you guys for answering my post here.

Cheers!

Comment: More specifically, this is where the operator "<-" is declared: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/blob/master/ObjectMapper/Core/Operators.swift